# Count number of times string matches a field across multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

Say I have a number of documents that look like this:

```
{
  'domain': 'www.stackoverflow.com',
  'time': 1380860676457
}
{
  'domain': 'www.google.com',
  'time': 1380860678001
}
{
  'domain': 'www.stackoverflow.com',
  'time': 1380860657233
}
```

What's the best way to end up with the following output?

```
{
  'domain': 'www.stackoverflow.com',
  'count': 2
}
```

Are there any performance considerations (a different way to store the logs?) if the initial collection contains, say, a million or more documents?

Comment: You can use aggregation function for this and can have index on domain  field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use aggregation. Something like:

```
db.sites.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: '$domain',
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }
}]);
```

This groups on the domain field and adds 1 to count for each document it finds. To make it look like the output you want you could also add a projection operation to your aggregation:

```
$project: {
  domain: '$_id',
  count: 1,
  _id: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is just group by `domain` and sum chunks. You could do it by collection method [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) like this:

```
db.cls.aggregate(
 {$group:{_id:"$domain", count: {$sum : 1}}},
 {$project:{_id:0, domain:"$_id", count:"$count"}}
)
```

First, `$group` gives you:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "www.google.com",
                    "count" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "www.stackoverflow.com",
                    "count" : 2
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

And the second, `$project` gives you:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "count" : 1,
                    "domain" : "www.google.com"
            },
            {
                    "count" : 2,
                    "domain" : "www.stackoverflow.com"
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Or you could do it just by collection method [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/):

```
db.cls.group({
  key: {domain:1},
  reduce: function(curr,result){ result.count += 1 },
  initial:{count:0}
})
```

And to speed up process you should have an index on `domain` field, as was mentioned by @AnujAneja.